# Changing CSS on an element based on a different elements attributes

Tags: javascript, css

I have an element that I want to display based on a different element having a "checked" attribute. I'm trying to figure out a way to do this with pure CSS.

Any suggestions?

The two elements are not siblings and do not have a parent-child relationship.

This is what I have tried, but it doesn't seem to be doing anything.

```
#toolbar:checked ~ #filterToolbar {
    display:none;
}
```

The `#toolbar` is a checkbox which should display or hide the `#filterToolbar` which is a toolbar on the page itself.

Comment: There are several different things you can do, depending on how the two elements relate to each other in the DOM. Show that relationship by showing your HTML. (When asking questions about how to do something with X and Y element, always show your structure.)

Comment: `input:checked ~ .someElement {...}`

Comment: Updated question to include relationship.

Comment: @qbolt well just remember CSS can't traverse up the DOM, only down. Give us a real example if you want a real answer.

Comment: Updated again to include some sample code. Apologies for not doing that in the beginning.

Comment: @qbolt we need the markup. the markup determines whether it's possible or not to target. Check out [mcve]

Comment: If your second element is a *descendant*, *following sibling* or *descendant of a following sibling* of the `<input>`, it's possible, using [`CSS combinators`](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_combinators.asp). Being an `<input>` it can't have descendants, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The two elements are not siblings and do not have a parent-child relationship.

If the two elements as unrelated as you indicate, there's no CSS-only solution; you'll need to use JavaScript (if you want to do it client side).

For instance, in a script tag at the end of the document, before the closing `</body>` tag:

```
(function() {
    var toolbar = document.getElementById("toolbar");
    var filterToolbar = document.getElementById("filterToolbar");
    function update() {
        if (toolbar.checked) {
            filterToolbar.style.display = "";     // Allows CSS default
        } else {
            filterToolbar.style.display = "none"; // Hides it
        }
    }
    update();
    toolbar.addEventListener("click", update, false);
})();
```

There are a thousand variations on that theme (my original answer used `querySelector`, but you've indicated now that both have IDs), but that's the idea.

Comment: Ok thank you very much! The other answer about the Checkbox helped me realize that it is out of scope so I'll have no choice but to use javascript.

Answer (score 0):

That is called [The Checkbox Hack](https://css-tricks.com/the-checkbox-hack/), and yes, it is very possible.

Howerver, due to limitations in CSS, the checked element must come *before* the element you want to affect, and it must be in the same scope or below.

This is what I mean:

```
<style type="text/css">
    /* This doesn't work because d1 comes before the checkbox */
    #awesome-checkbox:checked ~ #d1 {
        opacity: 0;
    }

    /* This works because d2 is after and parallel the checkbox */
    #awesome-checkbox:checked ~ #d2 {
        background-color: #000;
    }

    /* This works because d3 comes after and below the checkbox */
    #awesome-checkbox:checked ~ #d3 {
        color: #999;
    }

    /* This doesn't work because d4 is outside the checkbox's scope */
    #awesome-checkbox:checked ~ #d4 {
        display: block;
    }
</style>
<main>
    <div id="d1"> Oh noes </div>
    <input id="awesome-checkbox type="checkbox"/>
    <div id="d2">
        <div id="d3"> Oh yeah </div>
    </div>
</main>
<footer>
    <div id="d4"> Oh noes </div>
</footer>
```

Comment: *"The two elements **are not siblings** and do not have a parent-child relationship."* (my emphasis)

Comment: Yeah that wasn't there when I answered it haha but you're totally right, I just didn't bother deleting the answer.

Comment: Thanks for the information, turns out they are out of scope of each other.